# Iniitializing an array of unknown size

Tags: c++

Is it possible to have a function that returns an array of variable size?  My plan is to have the size of the returned array as the first member of the array (so ret_val[0] = # of members in ret_val).

The problem then becomes with initializing an array to the return value of that function.  `int moves[] = target_function()` wouldn't possibly compile.

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector`?

Comment: Agreed, use a std::vector - that's what it's for.

Comment: The size of array variables in C++ must be known at compile time. There's no way an array on the stack can be initialized from something of runtime-variable size. Kenny is right, this is what `vector` is for.

Comment: Any [introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will cover this.

Answer (score 7):

Every one is telling you to use a vector, but nobody is showing you how to do that.  Here's how:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> target_function(int size)
{
    std::vector<int> v(size);
    v[0] = size;
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> moves = target_function( my_favorite_int );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, +1 for just suggesting a vector instead of this beat-around-the-bush crap. What's the point in saying "Here's the code. Oh by the way, that's bad code don't use it."?

Answer (score 2):

You can return a pointer instead of an array:

```
int* moves = target_function();
```

But don't return a pointer to something you created on the stack as it will go out of scope when the function returns. You can dynamically allocate the array on the heap.

Comment: Sorry, but I -1 bad practices. The function should return a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using such hacks. There is std::vector ready for you to use. If you really want to go this way, here's the code that does what you want:

```
int *allocate(int size)
{
  int *res = new int[size];
  res[0] = size;
  return res;
}


// Prints "Yes, it's 42":
int *myArray = allocate(42);
if (myArray[0] == 42)
  std::cout << "Yes, it's 42!" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would use a pointer to an dynamically allocated array:

```
int* target_function() {
  int result* = new int[123];
  result[0] = 123;
  return result;
}

int *moves = target_function();
std::cout << moves[0] << " moves" << std::endl;
```

That being said, generally it is more practical and less error prone to use a standard library container like `std::vector<int>` instead. In C++ this is basically always the better choice than a raw array.

Answer (score 0):

Such array cannot be an automatic variable. It needs to be a pointer to a dynamically created array as Mark said.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't return an array.  You can return a pointer to dynamically allocated memory though:

```
int* moves = target_function();
// do stuff with moves
delete[] moves;
```

The `target_function()` will have to use `new` to allocate the memory.

Note that this is not ideal from a memory management point of view, because it's easy to forget to call `delete[]` on the returned array.  Instead, consider returning a `std::vector<int>`.